# How to read email as an attachment in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Currently, I am trying to fetch the attachments using the Azure logic app whenever any new mail arrives in the outlook, but any mail that has attachment as a mail, it is not able to fetch those attachments.

Comment: have you checked `Has Attachment` property there?

Comment: The has attachment returns true although the attachment array is empty. This happens only if the email as an attachment that is an email. For other attachments such as pdf or jpg so on, it works properly

Comment: Any update now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test with email attachment and will get this same problem, then I check the connector reference and I suppose I find the reason.

There is a description about outlook connector:

> Support for certain attachment types (EML, MSG, ICS) is currently
>   limited. These attachments will be skipped when processing emails.

More details you could refer to the [reference page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/outlook/).